# Two different results using wilcox.test in R

Tags: r

In R I have to vectors u and v. `length(u)=554` and `length(v)=1200`. I want to use wilcox.test to test if v and u are different. 
In R I type this

```
wilcox.test(u,v, alternative=greater)
```

I get a p-value equal 1. This means that u and v are not different. But when I type

```
 wilcox.test(u,v)
```

I get a very small p-value. So this gives me another conclusion, namely that u and v are different. How can that be ?

Comment: Why do you use 'greater'? What's your reason for using a one-sided test? And why are you surprised one-sided and two-sided testing yield different results?

Comment: Are you for real? You are testing completely two different hypothesis and you are surprised you've got different p-values?

Comment: The one hypothesis I test if u and v are equal against v is greater and in the second hyphotesis I test if u and v are equal against they are not equal. But the p-value should not be so different.

Comment: it's just because the difference is the other way around compared to what you tested with alternative greater... so yes, there is a significant difference but no, it's not the way you guessed............... (try `wilcox.test(u,v, alternative=less)`, you should get a small pvalue, about half the one you got with "two.sided" (the default option)...

Comment: So to confirm, do `wilcox.test(u,v, alternative=less)`

Comment: When I type that It say 'less' not found.

Comment: @OlePetersen I just made a typo : I forgot the quotes so `alternative="less"`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has been mentioned, you are doing wildly different statistical tests.  Visualizing the data would probably help you understand what is happening.

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- rnorm(50)
y <- rnorm(25, 10, 2)

DFrame<- data.frame(val = c(x, y),
                    group = rep(c("x", "y"), c(50, 25)))

ggplot(DFrame,
       aes(x = val,
           fill = group)) + 
  geom_histogram()
```

Now with the one-sided test:

```
wilcox.test(val ~ group, data = DFrame, alternative = "greater")
```

This test is testing against the alternative that `x` is greater than `y`.  Quite correctly, the test tells us that there is no evidence to indicate that `x` is greater than `y`, as is obvious from the histograms.

In the one sided test:

```
wilcox.test(val ~ group, data = DFrame)
```

Now we are asking if `x` is different than `y` in any direction.  Again, quite obvious, there is evidence to suggest that `x` is different than `y`, and we may even reasonably guess that `x` is less than `y`.

Remember, your p-values do *not* tell you anything about whether distributions are different (and especially not that they are the same).  The p-values only put an value on the strength of belief we have from our data about the alternative hypothesis, with a low p-value giving us stronger belief in the alternative.

Comment: I think you went "above and beyond" here, nice work.